# Can't modify list of lists to have a customized length

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, conditional-statements

I've written a script to make the length of all the lists at least `3` no matter what are their individual length at this moment.

Currently the list of lists I have:

```
item_list = [['1','2'],['3','4','5'],['2','4','5'],['1']]
```

I've tried with:

```
item_list = [['1','2'],['3','4','5'],['2','4','5'],['1']]
for item in item_list:
    if len(item)<3:
        item.extend([""])
    elif len(item)<2:
        item.extend([""]*2)

print(item_list)
```

Output I'm getting:

```
[['1', '2', ''], ['3', '4', '5'], ['2', '4', '5'], ['1', '']]
```

Desired output:

```
[['1', '2', ''], ['3', '4', '5'], ['2', '4', '5'], ['1', '','']]
```

***How can I make the length of all the lists at least `3` irrespective of their current length?***

Comment: hint `len(item)<3` has priority over `len(item)<2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for item in item_list:
    item += ['']*(3-len(item))
```

Answer (score 1):

You have written the order in reverse

```py
item_list = [['1','2'],['3','4','5'],['2','4','5'],['1']]
for item in item_list:
    if len(item)<2:
        item.extend([""]*2)
    elif len(item)<3:
        item.extend([""])


print(item_list)
```